# Tastypie foreign key dehydrate

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have the tastypie resource:

```
class ProjectPermissionResource(ModelResource):
    project = fields.ToOneField(ProjectResource, 'project', full=True, readonly=True)
...
```

As you see, the project resource is returning full with all fields.
I need to remove some fields, so I tried to use the dehydrate_project method:

```
def dehydrate_project(self, bundle):
    # delete some project fields here
    return bundle
```

But after adding this method I get "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". Stucked after this.

Need to delete some fields from project (in details I need only ot id,  name and so on...)

Comment: Have you tried to do this only in `dehydrate`? And did you solve it after all?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your own object from bundle.data
So basically something like this:
return bundle.data = {stuffs}